# Is it possible to peek at the data in a urllib2 response?

Tags: python, html, http, encoding, urllib2

I need to detect character encoding in HTTP responses.  To do this I look at the headers, then if it's not set in the content-type header I have to peek at the response and look for a "`<meta http-equiv='content-type'>`" header.  I'd like to be able to write a function that looks and works something like this:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/")
encoding = detect_html_encoding(response)
...
page_text = response.read()
```

However, if I do response.read() in my "detect_html_encoding" method, then the subseuqent response.read() after the call to my function will fail.

Is there an easy way to peek at the response and/or rewind after a read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def detectit(response):
   # try headers &c, then, worst case...:
   content = response.read()
   response.read = lambda: content
   # now detect based on content
```

The trick of course is ensuring that `response.read()` WILL return the same thing again if needed... that's why we assign that `lambda` to it if necessary, i.e., if we already needed to extract the content -- that ensures the same content can be extracted again (and again, and again, ...;-).

Answer (score 0):

1. If it's in the HTTP headers (not the document itself) you could use `response.info()` to detect the encoding
2. If you want to parse the HTML, save the response data:

   ```
   page_text = response.read()
   encoding = detect_html_encoding(response, page_text)
   ```

Comment: It can be (1) in the headers, (2) in the document or (3) absent (in which case I have to use chardet to detect it based on the characters in the document).

I can obviously pull the text out ahead of time, but the particular thing I'd like to do is basically allow me to avoid this type of approach.